# How to set marker on google map with dropdown?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to show marker on google map but marker not showing. I am selecting location from dropdown list when new location select marker not showing.

html code:

```
<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg">
           <option value="">Select city</option>
</select>
```

adding data from json:

```
  function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: {lat: 10, lng: 10}
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 10
                },
                draggable: true,
                map: map
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and at dropdown action js:

```
 $(document).on('change', '#state', function () {
                var state_id = $(this).val();

                    load_json_data1('state', state_id);

            });    

 function load_json_data1(id, parent_id)
                {
                    var lat = "";
                    var lang = "";
                    $.getJSON('1.json', function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            if (value.id == parent_id)
                            {
                                lat = value.lat;
                                lang = value.lang;
                            }

                        });
                        var newzoom = 1 * 18,
                                newlat = 1 * lat,
                                newlng = 1 * lang;
                        map.setZoom(newzoom);
                        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(newlat, newlng));

                    });
                }
```

My code is working upto lat and long only the marker is not showing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Declare `marker` outside the `initialize` function.

   `var marker;
   function initialize() {
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
               zoom: 10,
               center: {lat: 10, lng: 10}
           });
           marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: map.getCenter(),
               icon: {
                   path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                   scale: 10
               },
               draggable: true,
               map: map
           });
       }`
2. Change the position of `marker` in `load_json_data` function.

   `marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(newlat, newlng));`